# Output not coming while scraping and storing in database

Tags: python, sqlite, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I thought of storing my scraped data from amazon in a database using SQLite3. First I scraped and stored that in .csv format. It worked perfectly fine. But when I tried to store that in a database, it says:

Error:
**Cost = r.html.find('#priceblock_ourprice', first=True).text.strip()[1:]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**

The code I first used to get in .csv format was:

```
import csv
from requests_html import HTMLSession

csv_file = open('Laptop2.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Laptop','Cost', 'Savings'])

urls = ["https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B091HGK1B6/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A372Y0DOIAPTGJ&psc=1","https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08D3T9CK3/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?smid=A5QX138YR4YQ&psc=1","https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B096W63DZV/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?smid=A339C6POJNB9GM&psc=1","https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B0928TPR8H/ref=ox_sc_act_title_4?smid=A2YBFAXWY0FFA4&psc=1"]

for url in URLs:
    header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
    }

    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url, headers = header)
    r.html.render(timeout=120)

    title = r.html.find('#productTitle', first=True).text.strip()[:25]
    Cost = r.html.find('span#priceblock_ourprice', first=True).text.strip()[1:]
    Savings = r.html.find('.priceBlockSavingsString', first=True).text.strip()[1:]
    
    csv_writer.writerow([title, Cost, Savings])

csv_file.close()
```

Then I used this code to store in SQLite3 DB:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import sqlite3
import datetime

connection = sqlite3.connect('laptop.db')
c = connection.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Tracker(Date DATE, Name TEXT, price REAL, Savings REAL)''')

urls = ["https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B091HGK1B6/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A372Y0DOIAPTGJ&psc=1","https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08D3T9CK3/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?smid=A5QX138YR4YQ&psc=1","https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B096W63DZV/ref=ox_sc_act_title_3?smid=A339C6POJNB9GM&psc=1","https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B0928TPR8H/ref=ox_sc_act_title_4?smid=A2YBFAXWY0FFA4&psc=1"]

for url in urls:   

    header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
    }

    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url, headers = header)
    r.html.render(timeout=120)

    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    title = r.html.find('#productTitle', first=True).text.strip()[:25]
    Cost = r.html.find('#priceblock_ourprice', first=True).text.strip()[1:]
    Savings = r.html.find('.priceBlockSavingsString', first=True).text.strip()[1:]

    c.execute('''INSERT INTO Tracker VALUES(?,?,?,?)''', (current_date, title, Cost, Savings))

connection.commit()
c.execute(''' SELECT price FROM Tracker''')
results = c.fetchall()
print(results)
connection.close()
```

I feel like I made some mistake in sqlite3 or requests_html. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: It is not an issue with sqlite - Please focus on your `requests_html` part and the selector - Improving  your question, would be great.

Comment: Oh, I feel like the selector part is kinda correct but I'm not sure.

Comment: You have `span#priceblock_ourprice` in the first block of code for `Cost`, but just `#priceblock_ourprice` in your second block of code.

Answer (score 0):

We should not use the render function when there is no data in json form. So If I remove that line, this problem is solved.